# Change workbench SQL editor cursor / line highlight color

Tags: mysql-workbench

I found some great info on here about modifying Workbench's color scheme, but now that it's dark, the black cursor and dark blue line highlight blend in to the background almost entirely. The quick fix, of course, is to lighten the editor background, but I thought I'd ask if anyone has any idea how to modify the editor's line highlight and cursor colors.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color can be changed but you have to change the CSS
On linux it's here
/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml

Comment: can you add the line # or tag too

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench does not allow to customize colors on that level. The color schemes work only on Windows (where the OS provides already high contrast schemes). Windows is also handling any adjustment of cursor color, selection color and other standard colors (like window background). Further modifications are only possible for SQL syntax highlighting.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I neglected to mention that I'm actually using Ubuntu 16.04 / Unity. Does that make a difference so far as you're aware?

Comment: No difference. The color schemes only have been added in the Windows version of WB to match the support there for disabled people (e.g. those who are color blind or need high contrast), not so much to allow people customizing WB. Later we added 2 that match the Visual Studio color styles, as these are controversal and we wanted our users to have a choice. But nothing further than that.

Comment: Ok good to know. I appreciate the clarification. For anyone else looking for additional information about this issue, it is possible to obtain a dark theme for WB on Linux by using a combination of dark desktop theme (such as the Vivacious zblackout series for Unity) and modification of /usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml.

Comment: I don't get it. Weren't you asking for sql syntax color highlighting already?